# my bootstrap navbar is not responsive don't know why?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

my navbar on the desk seem to work fine and all however when i examine in a different screen size they don't seem to collapse or anything even though I am using bootstrap so that's the problem.

my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>lift Gym</title>

    <!-- bootstrap style -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <!--- customized style in index.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark" id="navBar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" id="heading" href="#">Lift Gym</a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navBar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active ml-5 mr-5" aria-current="page" href="#"
                >Home</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link ml-5 mr-5" href="#">about us </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link ml-5 mr-5" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link ml-5 mr-3" href="#">contact us </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <footer class="py-5 mt-5 fixed-bottom" id="footerStyle">
    </footer>

    <!-- bootstrap js -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my css file

```
body{
    background-color: black;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),
    url("https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1447561928/photo/fitness-gym-with-men-and-women-doing-plank-strong-and-exercise-for-muscle-cardio-and.jpg?s=2048x2048&w=is&k=20&c=Q5yRQMVSRkl5guXT6CsR_otVuC9l8TmqYKRtFIdfWgo=");
    background-position: left top;
    clip-path: polygon(20 50, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 10 50%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0; /* Remove default margin */
    min-height: 100vh; /* Set the body height to the full viewport height */
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide any content that goes beyond the body boundaries */



}


#navBar {
  height: 10vh;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#heading {
    font-size: 35px;
}

#footerStyle{
  background-color: rgb(55, 52, 52);
 /* width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;*/
}
```

when adjusting the screen-size to that of a mobile was hoping the navbar would collapse however that is not working neither my footer, your help is appreciated

Comment: forming sentences would motivate people to help you

Answer (score 0):

you didn`t use [Bootstrap responsive breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" id="navBar">
```

also check for [Bootstrap Navbar Doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)